# Is there an OnCreate Method for a Fragment whose View is set in InstantiateItem of a PagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `PagerAdaper` which uses the `InstantiateItem` Method to change the view being used.

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0: view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fs_datepicker, container, false);
                        break;
                    case 1: view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fs_date, container, false);
                        break;
                    default: view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fs_datepicker, container, false);
                }
```

Each different fragment layout file has different things that need to happen before they are started.

I need to set the labels of radio buttons as dates in `fs_date` and I need to create an `onFocusListener` for a `DatePickerDialog` in `fs_datepicker`.

Where should I run these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where should I run these methods?

You can run each method after their corresponding view is created. For example, set the labels of radio buttons as dates after inflating `R.layout.fs_date`. Code like this:

```
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                    switch (position){
                        case 0: view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fs_datepicker, container, false);
                       //  create an onFocusListener for a DatePickerDialog here.
                            break;
                        case 1: view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fs_date, container, false);
                       // set the labels of radio buttons as dates here.
                            break;                          
                        default: view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fs_datepicker, container, false);
                      //  create an onFocusListener for a DatePickerDialog here.
                    }
```

Comment: I tried that and was getting `NullPointerException`